# Does the authData change?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm building an android app that uses firebase to store users, each users is stored with the unique(?) uid that is generated when you call the method authWithPassword. However after awhile the previous uid doesn't match the current.
When does the uid change? Is there a time limit on how long the uid for user is the same?

this is how i log a user in:

```
this.db.authWithPassword(email, password, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {

                Log.i("login", "success"+authData.getUid());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

this is how i auth a user:

```
   private AuthData authenticate(String email, String password) {
        this.db.authWithPassword(email, password, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                Log.i("Authenticate", "success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.i("Authenticate", "fail");
            }
        });
        return db.getAuth();
    }
```

this is how a get the uid when a user is created:

```
private Firebase getUserRef(String email, String password) {
    Firebase userRef = this.db.child("Users").child(authenticate(email, password).getUid());
    return userRef;
}
```

Comment: Calling `authWithPassword` with the same email should return the same `uid` every time. Is there any way you can capture the behavior you're describing in a single piece of code that I can run, e.g. in a unit test?

Comment: Noticed that it happens when i tried to push some template data to firebase and then ran the app as usual. It's resolved